# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database ' register_login'

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure what is going on here. I have changed the database name. I have gone into phpMyAdmin and copy and pasted the name just to make sure the database was right. here is my code.

```
class DB {
  private static $_instance = null;
  private $_pdo,
          $_query,
          $_error = false,
          $_results,
          $_count = 0;

  private function __construct() {
    try{
      $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname= ' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
    } catch(PDOException $e){
      die($e->getMessage());
    }
  }

  public static function getInstance(){
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
      self::$_instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
  }
}
```

Here is the class for config,

```
class Config {
  public static function get($path = null){
    if($path){
      $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
      $path = explode('/', $path);

      foreach($path as $bit){
        if(isset($config[$bit])){
         $config = $config[$bit];
          }
        }
      return $config;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here is the init.php file I have made.

```
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
  'mysql' => array(
    'host' =>  '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'db' => 'register_login'
  ),
  'remember' => array(
    'cookie_name' => 'hash',
    'cookie_expiry' => 604800
  ),
  'session' => array(
    'session_name' => 'user'
  )
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
  require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
```

And here is the index

```
require_once 'core/init.php';

$user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'Taylor'));
 echo $user;
if(!$user->count()){
  echo 'No user in table';
} else {
  foreach($user->results() as $user){
    echo $user->username, '<br>';
  }
}
```

Comment: `have changed the database name` where? you renamed your db in mysql? or you changed the `'db'` parameter in your config?

Comment: No I have tried changing the db name in init file to one of my other databases names and then it still gives the same error just with the name of that database.

Comment: `Unknown database ' register_login'` see that space before `register_login`? There shouldn't be any spaces in here `dbname= ' . Config::get('mysql/db')` so you need to change that to >>>  `dbname='. Config::get('mysql/db')` and make  sure there are no other spaces on that line.

Comment: Thank you @Fred-ii- that was it. I always do something silly like that !

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post an answer for this if you don't mind. @NewbieCoder

Comment: @NewbieCoder You get 2 reputaiotn points for every answer you accept.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I got it! Thank you!

Comment: @NewbieCoder *Grazie, grazie mille!* ;-) cheers and welcome to Stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database ' register_login'` in your error.

You see that space before `register_login`? It's looking for a database of that name **BUT** with a space before it, so of course it doesn't exist, in turn throwing you that error.

There shouldn't be any spaces in here `dbname= ' . Config::get('mysql/db')` so you need to change that to `dbname='.Config::get('mysql/db')` and make  sure there are no other spaces on that line.

- The PDO DSN should not contain any spaces.